# ASP.NET MVC Showing previously selected radio (when 2x radiobuttonfor exist)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have:

```
<label class="radio inline">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ViewModelForCar.CarTypeID, CarType.CoolTypeID) Cool car
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ViewModelForCar.CarTypeID, CarType.LameTypeID) Lame car
</label>
```

But when a form is submitted, and result invalid, and the page re-loads, the wrong radio the first radio is always marked as selected, even if I marked the second one as selected. I'm not keen on using radiobuttonlist because I have custom markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC does not how to rebind the model back because you have two radio buttons named the same.

Modifying the radio buttons to

```
<label class="radio inline">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ViewModelForCar.CoolTypeID, CarType.CoolTypeID) Cool car
</label>
<label class="radio inline">
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ViewModelForCar.LameTypeID, CarType.LameTypeID) Lame car
</label>
```

will give you two distinct radio buttons. Then you can handle working which radio button is selected in the controller.

Comment: I used my own radiobuttonlistfor adapter, this is the best way TO DO IT i THINK!